# How to make a for loop in google maps polygon path creator?

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps

I have a small problem.I made a script in javascript for creating a polygon path and then showing it on map.But i didn't used a for loop .And for that reason my script works for a polygon only with 4 point.But if i have more than 4 point i need a for loop.Any idea how to do it?
  This is the script for 4 points:

```
 var triangleCoords = [
                    {lat: <?php echo $POLYGON[0] ?>, lng: <?php echo $POLYGON[1] ?>},
                    {lat: <?php echo $POLYGON[2] ?>, lng: <?php echo $POLYGON[3] ?>},
                    {lat: <?php echo $POLYGON[4] ?>, lng: <?php echo $POLYGON[5] ?>},
                    {lat: <?php echo $POLYGON[6] ?>, lng: <?php echo $POLYGON[7] ?>},
                    {lat: <?php echo $POLYGON[0] ?>, lng: <?php echo $POLYGON[1] ?>}
                  ];
```

Comment: the answer depends upon your data

Comment: And the usual process is that you give it a try and then ask for help getting it working properly. So if you have a try and then show us what you have, we are more than willing to help you fix it. However we dont write code for you from a spec

Comment: you should use forin loop when working with object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your poligon struct  you could use a loop step 2

```
<?php                  
   for ( $i = 0 ; $i< (count($POLYGON)/2); $i+=2 ){
      $innerString = '{lat:' .$POLIGON[$i] . ', lng:' .$POLIGON[$i+1] . '},';
   }
    $innerString = strleft($innerString, length($innerstring)-1); // remove the last comma because some browser version (Opera and Chrome) 
                                                            // have problem  with this js notation 
?>

var triangleCoords = [
     <?php echo $innerString; ?>
 ];
```

Comment: it's a good idea.But i swear to god i have one hour to see what happens when i put your code in my page nothing else shows .Nothing.I think is a  syntax error or something but i don't know which/

Comment: i have update the answer using strleft () for get the left   string minus last comma .. anyway  you can take a look a t the code generated  using control+U and check if the var triangleCoords contain the right json code .

Comment: it gives me "failed to load resources 500(internal server error)"

Comment: found it .It's not $i+2 it's $i+=2

Comment: @Andrei   .  correct answer  updated ..